# Incrementing list items in jinja2 templates (appengine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a list of values in my template, which I need to increment based on some conditions. Something like this:

```
{% set samplelist=[0,0,0] %}

{% if condition %}
<p>some text</p>
{% set samplelist[0]=samplelist[0]+listpassedbymainfile[0] %}
{% endif %}
```

I keep getting this error when I try to run the above code:

**TemplateSyntaxError: expected token '=', got '['**

Is this not supported, if so, is there a work around ?

Comment: are you missing the closing `%}`?

Comment: Sorry, I just missed that here, not in the actual code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you can't use jinja in the same way as you would use python.  You can, however, unroll your in-place modification with a proper assignment.  Note that your list will now be the same from the first element on, but with a different value in its first slot.  We can change the assignment to capture the full, new state of `samplelist` in that way:

```
{% set samplelist = [samplelist[0] + listpassedbymainfile[0]] + samplelist[1:] %}
```

Comment: @Shan if that worked for you then you should also accept the answer...! The little green check mark under the vote counting..

Comment: @Lipis Done, sorry I had replied via my phone that's why couldn't do it earlier